# Can't set text to textview in Samsung Tab 3

Tags: java, android, textview, runtime-error, settext

My application produces an error when opening the Activiti. This error has only Samsung Tab 3 and other devices running stable. Dear profissionaly please advise how to correct the mistake.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView share=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sharetext);
    share.setText("Share"); // error in this line :(
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharetext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{tj.afkor.makon/tj.afkor.makon.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at tj.afkor.makon.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:179)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
... 11 more
```

Grateful for any advice

Comment: your code looks perfect

Comment: @SagarLimbani my problem only in Samsung Tab 3

Comment: Your code looks fine. Might be a case of an id conflict as the findviewbyid() lookup failed for some reason. Try cleaning your project, uninstalling your app on the Tab and running it again. Also, try changing your textview id to something else and see if that works.